# Yellowbrick change legend and add title

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, yellowbrick

I created a graph with yellowbrick RadViz:

```
visualizer = RadViz(classes=labels)
visualizer.fit(X, y) 
visualizer.transform(X)  
visualizer.show()
```

As you can see, the legend overrides some of the feature names:
[image]
Moreover, I want to edit the title.
I tried with:

```
visualizer.ax.set_title("new title")
visualizer.fig.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc=0, borderaxespad=0., title = "level")
```

But `set_title`  had no effect. using `fig.legend`
 , a new legend was indeed created but I couldn't remove the original legend.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify the title of a Yellowbrick plot using the `title` parameter, and use the `size` parameter to increase the size of the axes, which may help with overlapping labels. Size is specified as a tuple of pixel dimensions:

```py
from yellowbrick.features import RadViz
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_occupancy


X, y = load_occupancy()

visualizer = RadViz(
    classes=["occupied", "vacant"], 
    title="My custom title", 
    size=(800, 600)
)
visualizer.fit(X, y)
visualizer.transform(X)
visualizer.show()
```

[image: Radial visualization with custom title and size]

Alternatively, it is possible to skip the step of adding the Yellowbrick legend and title by circumventing the visualizer's `show()` and `finalize()` methods, and then directly modifying the ax object using whatever custom legend position you need for your plot:

```py
from yellowbrick.features import RadViz
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_occupancy


X, y = load_occupancy()

visualizer = RadViz()
visualizer.fit(X, y)
visualizer.transform(X)

custom_viz = visualizer.ax
custom_viz.set_title("New title")
custom_viz.figure.legend(
    bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), 
    borderaxespad=0.0,
    title="level",
    loc=0,
)
custom_viz.figure.show()
```